# Folder Showing up as a File when viewed via Samba on a NetApp

Tags: debian, samba, netapp

we want to change files on our [NetApp](http://www.netapp.com/us/) file server, and on every change of these files - a Debian machine duplicates the files to two other shares.

Because of the duplication method we're using [lsync](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/), we need to mount the Samba share (of the NetApp storage) and re-share it with Samba, and we are doing all the changes from the share of the Debian machine instead of the NetApp.

The problem is that sometimes at some tree levels we see the folders as files instead of folders.

For example the tree looks like this:

```
/
--fol1
 +--fol5
   +--fol6
--fol2
 +--fol3
   +--fol4
```

All the folders in the **fol4/fol6** level, no matter what is their parent, looks like it is a file.

**NOTE:** From the Debian system all looks fine, the problem is only noticeable on the windows machines that see the Samba share on the Debian machine.

Some idea how to solve the problem?

the smb.conf file:

```
guest account = nobody
map to guest = bad user
disable netbios = yes
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=242144
strict sync = no
acl check permissions = no
oplocks = False
level2oplocks = False
sync always = no

[reshare]
comment =reshare the netapp with debian to able to see the file change events
path = /netapp/
hosts allow =host1;host2;
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
force user = user1;
workgroup = SERVERS

server string = %h server
dns proxy = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
encrypt passwords = true
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
```

Comment: can you please re-read the edits I made to your question and make sure that I didn't lose any of your intent?

Comment: Can you also please share your lsyncd config file and/or the lsync command itself?

Comment: about the lsync - it is not the problem.
here is the workflow:
working on development computer, dev1
copy from dev1 to samba share in deb1
the lsync on the debian should copy the files to iis1 and iis2 servers.
my problem is before the lsync, in the way between dev1 and deb1.
when deb1 see the change it copying the files, 
but i cannot do the changes in deb1 because of i dont see the folders.

Comment: I have the same problem and can't find a solution. This is the only info I found in this case. Is there any progress in the issue, a solution maybe? Thanks,
Zoltan

Comment: i dont know but now i think about that i do it in another share and it is not happening. i will try to check for differences between them...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cifs for netapp share, don't reshare the netapp share, try to use samba dfs.

This an example from samba official doc.

```
root# cd /export/dfsroot
root# chown root /export/dfsroot
root# chmod 755 /export/dfsroot
root# ln -s msdfs:storageA\\shareA linka
root# ln -s msdfs:serverB\\share,serverC\\share linkb

Example 20.1. smb.conf with DFS Configured
[global]
netbios name = GANDALF
host msdfs = yes
[dfs]
path = /export/dfsroot
msdfs root = yes
```

In this way, your debian is like a proxy for the netapp shares